# Type mismatch error with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data that is in varying formats such as, B, KB, MB, GB, and TB. I have written code to remove the units and convert to GB. My issue is that The last section 'b to kb' causes a type mismatch error. I cant understand why as I have applied the same code to each conversion? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Sub RemoveUnits()
Dim r As Range
Dim x As Long
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
w = r.Value

'GB
     If InStr(w, "gb") > 0 Then
        r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 2)
        Debug.Print (r.Value)
    'No conversion required
'TB
    ElseIf InStr(w, "tb") > 0 Then
        r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 2)
        r = r * 1024
        Debug.Print (r.Value)
   'Convert tb to gb
'MB
    ElseIf InStr(w, "mb") > 0 Then
      r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 2)
      r = (1 / 1024) * r
      Debug.Print (r.Value)
'Convert mb to gb
 'KB
    ElseIf InStr(w, "kb") > 0 Then
      r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 2)
      r = (1 / 1048576) * r
      Debug.Print (r.Value)
'B to KB
    ElseIf InStr(w, "b") > 0 Then
      r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 1)
      r = (1 / 1024) * r
      debung.Print (r.Value)




    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems.

1. You have set `r` as range.
2. You are trying to multiply a numeric value with a string value. Convert the string to a numeric value and then perform the necessary action.

For example

```
r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 2)
r = r * 1024
```

Try this

```
r = Val(Trim(r)) * 1024
```

Similarly change `r = (1 / 1024) * r` to `r = (1 / 1024) * Val(Trim(r))` and so on...

Note: I am assuming that `r` stores a numeric value as string.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** Try use the common `Debug.Print` instead of the esoteric `debung.Print` in your last `ElseIf`. Usually code highlighting is a good friend. And also, supplemental meta-irony points for the fact that the code that helps you debug causes the exceptions in the first place. :-)

**Suggestion:** `Left$` expects a `String` as first parameter, while you pass an `Excel.Range` object. Sometimes is not okay...

Try (and fix this for all your code):

```
Sub RemoveUnits()
        '... Local declarations'
        Dim w  As String

        For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                Let w = CStr(r.Value)

                ' ... The other cases'

                ElseIf InStr(w, "b") > 0 Then
                        Let w = Left$(w, Len(w) - 1)
                        Let r.Value = (1 / 1024) * CDbl(w)
                        Debug.Print r.Value
                End If
        Next r
End Sub
```

The suggestion part is similar to the answer of [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout), with the difference that it uses for calculations the `String` variable as an intermediate, not the `Range` one.

Comment: Except the `debung.Print`, I am not sure, how is your answer different than mine :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi Siddharth. I hope that you don't take personally the fact that I wrote an answer that shares similarities with yours. Also, I hope that your comment doesn't imply that I *stole* the answer from you. :-)

Comment: If I would have taken it personally, I would have already downvoted ;) No I am not saying that you stole the answer. The reason why I said that, because I don't see a reason for posting a similar answer...